What is the difference between 娜, 那 and 哪?
Here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-%E9%82%A3-and-%E5%93%AA, I found difference between  那 and 哪. I can recognize 娜 women in the first compound character. Could you confirm the meaning ? Is it something applied for women ?


the difference between 那, 哪 and 娜

They are very different.
那：that (the opposite of 这，  this)
哪：which, where, how
哪座房子是他们的？
Which house is yours?
你去哪了？
Where did you go? (actually: Which place did you go?)
你能听出这是哪支曲子吗？
Can you hear what tune this is? (actually: Can you hear which tune this is?)
哪：用于反问，表示肯定、否定或加强语气 [why;how]
哪：used in rhetorical questions, expresses affirmation, negation or emphatic tone.
恨恨哪可论?
How can one talk of hatred?
娜: 婀娜( ē'nuó)∶
形容姿态柔美
describes a gentle and beautiful appearance.
高的，苗条的，婀娜多姿的。
Tall, slender and graceful.
Otherwise, 娜 is used in transliterating the na sound in foreign, mainly female, names, like: Anna: 安娜（女子名）.

"娜":



[nuó] elegant, graceful, delicate.  "婀娜[ē nuó]" - (woman's) elegant/graceful/delicate posture/look.




[nà] used in woman's surname name; popular for translating foreign woman's name ending in "na" - "Dianna - 黛安娜"




The character 娜 (nà) is related to 那 (nà) and 哪 (nǎ) phonetically (i.e., in relation to its pronunciation), and not semantically (i.e., in relation to its meaning).
The character 娜 appears in women's names, like the tennis player 李娜 (Lǐ Nà), or in translitions of names, like 安娜 (Ānnà; a transliteration of "Anna") and 蒙娜丽莎 (Méngnàlìshā) = Mona Lisa.
I checked a few dictionaries as to what 娜 means (like this), but all they said was it's used in women's names, and didn't specify any meaning.  Dong-Chinese lists it as:

elegant, graceful, delicate; (phonetic na); used esp. in female names such as Anna 安娜[An​nà] or Diana 黛安娜[Dài​'ān​nà]

